# c fscanf save by pattern

Tags: c

This is the line i'm trying to split, from the start until the `:`, eat any whitespace and from there onwards:

```
file1: file2,file3,file4
```

And my code is:

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%s: %s",map[i].name, map[i].filesNeeded) == 1)
{
   printf("%s %s\n",map[i].name, map[i].filesNeeded);
   i++;
}
```

The second parameter is never saved. the result is:

```
file1: 
file2,file3,file4
```

instead of:

```
file1 file2,file3,file4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, fscanf will increment the return for each item matched, so it should be == 2.

Also, you will want to use %[^:] instead of %s as the %s won't know when to stop.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char test[] = "one: two,three";

  char part1[20];
  char part2[20];

  printf("%i\n", sscanf(test, "%[^:]: %s", part1, part2));

  printf("%s %s\n", part1, part2);
}
```

Output:

```
2
one two,three
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%[^:]: %s",map[i].name, map[i].filesNeeded) == 2)
{
   printf("%s %s\n",map[i].name, map[i].filesNeeded);
   i++;
}
```

I have modified the code.You can have a try like it.